# Visual Studio 2010 not recognizing MSTests

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

I have a project containing some MSTest unit tests, however, when I try to run them the test runner doesn't notice them.

I have the `ProjectTypeGuids` in the `.proj` file as so:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

The test are attributed correctly and public, as so:

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

```
namespace WebService.UnitTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class MyTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void MyTest()
        {
            Assert.Fail("At least the test is running!");
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run (All tests in solution), I see the message `No tests were run because no tests are loaded or the selected tests are disabled`.

What else do I need to change to get the test runner to tread this project as a test project?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this just worked, but I removed the project from the solution and then added it again.

If anyone can give me any advise on what just happened then it would be greatly appreciated.